# Moving group of nodes to new node

Tags: xml, xslt, move

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<root>
 <prices>....</prices>
 <image1>
  <img1>....</img1>
 </image1>
 <image2>
  <img2>....</img2>
 </image2>
 <image3>
  <img3>....</img3>
 </image3>
 <data>....</data>
</root>
```

But I would need to move image1, image2, and image3 to the end of root node into so it would look like this

```
<root>
<prices>....</prices>
<data>....</data>
<sab>
<sab1>
<store>
<tab>
<cell1>...</cell1>
<cell2>
<image1>
<img1>....</img1>
</image1>
<image2>
<img2>....</img2>
</image2>
<image3>
<img3>....</img3>
</image3>
<cell2>
<tab>
<store>
<sab1>
<sab>
</root>
```

I tried everything, but can not get it to work properly.

Comment: Could you include your best code attempt into your question? Maybe that would good point to start. Otherwise, you would oblige others to actually write the code for you. That's not the point of StackOverflow. Also, could you indent your desired output to make the tag hierarchy more obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted desired results ends with `<tab><store><sab1><sab></root>`, that is not well-formed XML, with all those start tags like `<tab>`. Assuming you want

```
<root>
<prices>....</prices>
<data>....</data>
<sab>
<sab1>
<store>
<tab>
<cell1>...</cell1>
<cell2>
<image1>
<img1>....</img1>
</image1>
<image2>
<img2>....</img2>
</image2>
<image3>
<img3>....</img3>
</image3>
</cell2>
</tab>
</store>
</sab1>
</sab>
</root>
```

you would set up a template for the root element

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::image1 | self::image2 | self::image3)]"/>
    <sab>
    <sab1>
    <store>
    <tab>
    <cell1>...</cell1>
    <cell2>
      <xsl:copy-of select="image1 | image2 | image3"/>
    </cell2>
    </tab>
    </store>
    </sab1>
    </sab>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```